# Skips the output where I enter my username

Tags: c

I need to make a journal/planner where I can have a username and password login and set up a login and account if you already don't have one. I need to then later be able to login using that and access my journal. In there I can put in entry's and save it. So that when I quit the program and start the program again, once I login, I can access the planner again.

So my problem is that for setting up my account, I need to allow the user to enter a username and password, but when I start the program, it skips the part where I can type in my username and goes straight to the password. The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1000

void signUp (char username [SIZE], char password [SIZE], char name [SIZE], int age) {
    printf("Sign Up Procedure: \n");
    printf("\nPlease enter your username: ");
    gets(username);
    printf("\nPlease enter a password: ");
    gets(password);
    printf("\nEnter your full name: ");
    gets(name);
    printf("\nEnter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Username: %s, Password: %s, Full Name: %s, Age: %d", username, password, name, age);
}

void logIn(char username [SIZE], char password [SIZE]) {

}

int main() {
    printf("1. Log In\n");  // Enter 1 for logging in
    printf("2. Sign Up\n"); // Enter 2 for signing up
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    char username [SIZE];
    char password [SIZE];
    char name [SIZE];
    int age;

    int keepGoing = 0;

    while (keepGoing == 0){
        switch (choice) {
        case (1):
            logIn (username, password);
            keepGoing = 1;
            break;
        case (2):
            signUp (username, password, name, age);
            keepGoing = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter a choice from the given options");
            keepGoing = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    FILE * pfile;

    pfile = fopen("Planner.txt", "w");

    fputs("Planner", pfile);

    fclose(pfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you ask for the username or the password?

Comment: `while (keepGoing == 0) { do_stuff }` -> while keepGoing is false, keep going... (not an error, just very very bad naming)

Comment: I ask for the username in the signUp method in the very beginning

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is so dangerous it should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Answer (score 1):

Your first `scanf()`

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

is reading an integer, so it leaves the newline character in the input buffer.

Then when you try to get the username:

```
gets(username);
```

It picks up that newline character and assigns it to `username`.  I would suggest reading up on `C` input and why `scanf()` can be dangerous and tricky to use, especially when mixing integer and string input and when using it with other `C` input functions.

Comment: what should i use instead of scanf() then?

Comment: you can just swallow this new line by adding getchar() after scanf

Comment: Yeah, you could just add another input statement and eat up the extra newline, but that is not really building good coding practice.  `fgets()` is generally preferred over `scanf()`...this is a great read...http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html